# generating matrix for a recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm, math, recurrence

> Answered on Math.SE, [generating matrix for a recurrence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124178/generating-matrix-for-a-recurrence-relation)

for the recurrence `f(n)=a*f(n-1)+b*f(n-2)+c*f(n-3)+d*f(n-4)` , how can one get the generating matrix so that it can be solved by matrix exponentiation?

For `f(n)=a*f(n-1)+b*f(n-2)+c*f(n-3)` the corresponding generating matrix is:

```
| a  0  c |   |  f(n)  |   | f(n+1) |
| 1  0  0 | x | f(n-1) | = |  f(n)  |
| 0  1  0 |   | f(n-2) |   | f(n-1) |
```

so how to get the same for required recurrence?
Also what should be the procedure for any recurrence which may be of the form :

`f(n)=a*f(n-1)+b*f(n-2)+c*f(n-3)+..+someconstant*f(n-k)` ?

Thanks.

Comment: @MitchWheat: sorry but that's what i wanted to know..how to make an effort to solve this recurrence , i already know the matrix if the recurrence has 3 terms but how to extend it?

Comment: @pranay You might have more luck on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @dbr: thanks i'll post my question there